# What is the difference between Freezable.Clone() & Freezable.CloneCurrentValue() methods

Tags: wpf, freezable

The documentation says

**Clone**-
"Creates a modifiable clone of the System.Windows.Freezable, making deep copies
of the object's values. When copying the object's dependency properties,
this method copies expressions (which might no longer resolve) but not animations
or their current values."

**CloneCurrentValue**-
"Creates a modifiable clone (deep copy) of the System.Windows.Freezable using
its current values."

It means both do deep copy. Then what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the documentation correctly, `Clone` also copies the binding expressions. So if a property of the object is bound, it remains bound in the copy.

`CloneCurrentValues`, on the other hand, only copies the current values, as the name implies. Bindings are not kept, so the values in the copy won't be updated if the source of the binding is modified.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, I should have understood it.